# How to negate 'remove all folders' mistake in Sublime Text project

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, text-editor, sublimetext3

In Sublime Text (2 & 3) I find I accidentally remove all folders from the project when I don't want to (this option is poorly placed in the menu, with no obvious undo or warning and is arguably similar to a 'clear' button on a form).

I often have many folders open in a project each one a leaf in the folder tree structure, which is my workflow, so naturally this is a nasty break in my work if it's accidentally triggered!

I would like to know if I can either disable this option or undo it if I accidentally trigger it?

Comment: Proper backups and version control systems is the best way of handling all accidental file/directory removal.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg - fair point, I should version control the sublime project files then I could recover from this easily, nice suggestion, and probably a better solution than any direct answer to the question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aside from a backup, a version control system, or a versioning feature on your file system, there is unfortunately no way of undoing the "Remove all Folders from Project" command, because as soon as the command is fired the folders are removed from the `.sublime-project` file, and the file is saved. However, there is a way to disable the command. The methods vary between Sublime Text 2 and 3, so I'll go over 2 first.

In Sublime Text 2, click on **`Preferences -> Browse Packages...`** to open the `Packages` folder, whose location varies by operating system. Go into the `Default` folder, and open `Main.sublime-menu` in Sublime (it's a JSON file). Search for "`close_folder_list`" and find the line that looks like this (it's line 737 in version 2.0.2):

```js
{ "command": "close_folder_list", "caption": "Remove all Folders from Project", "mnemonic": "m" },
```

Now, you can either simply delete the entire line, or comment it out by putting `//` as the first characters on the line. Save the file, then click on the **`Project`** menu to see that the option is gone.

If you're using Sublime Text 3, you'll need a workaround to access the `Packages/Default` folder and its contents, as in this version most of the packages that you would normally have seen in the `Packages` directory in ST2 are zipped into `.sublime-package` files and stored elsewhere. However, there's a plugin for that! Make sure you have [Package Control](https://sublime.wbond.net) installed, then open the Command Palette, type ***`pci`*** to bring up `Package Control: Install Package`, and search for [`PackageResourceViewer`](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/PackageResourceViewer). Install it, open the Command Palette again, type ***`prv`***, and select `PackageResourceViewer: Edit Package Resource`. Scroll down to `Default`, click on it or hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, then scroll down to `Main.sublime-menu` and select it to open it for editing. You can now follow the instructions above to find the line containing "`close_folder_list`" (it should be line 795) and either delete it or comment it out.

If you'd like to keep the menu item, but move it to a different spot, you can do that as well. For example, if you'd like it at the very bottom of the menu, separated by a divider, delete the original line, put the cursor below the "`refresh_folder_list`" line, and paste in the following:

```js
            { "caption": "-" },
            { "command": "close_folder_list", "caption": "Remove all Folders from Project", "mnemonic": "m" },
```

so it looks like this:

[image: Project menu (modified)]